# sed: How to remove entire line matching specific string?

Tags: bash, sed

I am having issues removing the entire line in the sample.txt

```
   cat sample.txt

   XYZ   -2.4   DNW
   ZYY   -2.4   138
   ZZZ   -3.4   200
   ZZZ   -2.4   DNW 

  sed '/DNW/d' sample.txt >> output.txt

  cat output.txt 

   XYZ   -2.4                 #removes the DNW, but not the entire line
   ZYY   -2.4   138
   ZZZ   -3.4   200
   ZZZ   -2.4
```

What I need is this:

```
    cat output.txt 


   ZYY   -2.4   138      #Need the entire lines removed that matched the 3rd column string DNW
   ZZZ   -3.4   200
```

I am new to bash and was wondering whether there is an option to remove the entire line in the text file matching the search criteria?

Thank you!

p.s. I would be interested in possible solutions primarily using bash. However, I am starting to play with python as well and if there are solutions I'd be glad to learn those as well.

**UPDATE**

It turns out that my original sample.txt file was not formatted somehow correctly. The following fixed the issue, as it changed the rows into the comma delimited format (e.g. x, y, c = treated as a line).

```
   cp sample.txt sample.csv
   sed '/DNW/d' sample.csv > output.txt #Please note any of the below user suggested answers/solutions work!
```

Cheers and thanks for all the help!

Comment: I think in this case, `grep -v` would be even easier than `sed`.

Comment: That sed command is correct. You are appending to the output file, so: what was in "output.txt" before your sed command?

Comment: There was nothing in the output.txt file, just told it to write the result into it. Perhaps not the appropriate way to do it?

Comment: `>>` means to append to an existing file (or create if it does not exist). `>` means write (and truncate if it does exist). See http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Redirections

Comment: @user1698774: The difference between `>>` and `>` in shell direction is effectively the same as the difference between `'a'` and `'w'` in Python (and most other languages with `open`-like functions), which is why glenn jackman asked you about the `'a'` in a comment on my answer and about the `'>>'` in a comment on the question. If you're appending to the end of the file, then looking at the first few lines, they're going to still be old, incorrect versions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is even easier with `grep` than `sed`:

```
grep -v DNW sample.txt >> output.txt
```

If you want to do it in Python, it's a lot more verbose, but not actually much harder:

```
with open('sample.txt') as fin, open('output.txt', 'a') as fout:
    for line in fin:
        if 'DNW' not in line:
            fout.write(fin)
```

Or, if you want it a little briefer (but probably harder for a novice to understand):

```
with open('sample.txt') as fin, open('output.txt', 'a') as fout:
    fout.writelines(line for line in fin if 'DNW' not in line)
```

Comment: Both those still only remove the actual "DNW" string, but not the entire line.

Comment: @user1698774, change `open('output.txt', 'a')` to `open('output.txt', 'w')` and then what do you get?

Comment: @user1698774: No, all three of those definitely remove the entire line. There is no way that Python code could possibly write out an edited line; it either writes the line as-is, or writes nothing.

Comment: Any way I can share the sample file with you? I've ran the code exactly (grep etc..) and it removes only the string, but not the line itself. Could the .txt file actually not have the data in lines and that is causing the issue (e.g. the columns are treated separately?). Thanks.

Comment: @user1698774: By "bash", you mean the `grep` one-liner? Again, that isn't possible. `grep` selects lines that match (or, with the `-v` flag, that _don't_ match) a regexp; it doesn't modify the lines. Meanwhile, you already did share the sample file, in your question. That's how jshort and others were able to test it.

Comment: The file I have is a lot longer, I just replicated what the format looks like. Could it be that in the actual file the columns are separated somehow, so it is not treating them as lines?

Comment: @user1698774: It's possible that you're, e.g., mixing up different kinds of newlines or something. First, make sure the problem isn't just the one glenn jackman brought up: if there are already old, incorrect lines lying around in `output.txt`, and you append new lines after them, that doesn't fix the old, incorrect ones at the start of the file. Second, try to reproduce the failure with the short example; failing that, try the first few lines of the real file.

Comment: @user1698774: Then finally, if you've done those steps and are sure you have a real problem that can be 100% reproduced with the real file but can't be reproduced with any small sample you can think of, then post the file somewhere online and sharable (http://pastebin.com, https://gist.github.com/, Google Docs, a public DropBox folder, whatever you prefer) and add a link to the shared location in your question.

Comment: This fixed the issue: I converted the .txt > .csv and ran the sed, grep, python code. They all worked beautifully. It appeared that the original .txt file was not appropriately formatted. Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 7):

You got it nearly right:

`sed '/DNW/d' sample.txt >> output.txt`

Comment: That was a typo. Thanks tho! The code will still only remove only the string that was searched and not the entire line.

Comment: that's strange. what OS and sed version do you have?

Comment: I am on OSX 10.9.4; not sure what sed verison (tried sed -V, without success).

Comment: try with `sed -e` and eventually `--posix`, there is not reason that this sed action remove only the work (there is no action for that, `d` only delete FULL line). You could maybe debug with a `'=;l;/DNW/d'` to be sur there is no hidden New Line (ex from WinDOS file source)

Comment: @user1698774: Unlike Linux, *BSD (including OS X) treats core userland tools like `sed` as part of the OS rather than separate projects, so they don't get independent version numbers. The closest thing to a version number for OS X 10.9.4's sed is "OS X 10.9.4", "Darwin 13.3.0", or "FreeBSD 6.0".

Comment: @NeronLeVelu: `--posix` is a GNU extension to sed; there's no such thing in *BSD. (And it shouldn't be needed, because unlike GNU, BSD sed won't add features that would make it no longer a strict superset of POSIX, even when POSIX is stupid.)

Answer (score 1):

Your sed command works for me on OSX.  Try to be super explicit and try this:

```
sed '/^.*DNW.*$/d' sample.txt >> output.txt
```

Comment: Same, only removes the string. I am starting to think that the .txt file has the columns somehow separated..

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `awk`

```
awk '!/DNW/' file
   ZYY   -2.4   138
   ZZZ   -3.4   200
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the -i switch for sed will update the file based on pattern

```
sed -rie 's/DNW.+$//g' file
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Nice answer but it could be even more helpful if you include the documentation for the specific option `-i`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).